# NODEJS - How to import modules like import.module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I was reading the source code of Foliate- A Javascript Epub reader and then I came across this

```
const { Gtk, Gio } = imports.gi
const ngettext = imports.gettext.ngettext
const { mimetypes, readJSON, sepHeaderFunc } = imports.utils
const { EpubViewAnnotation } = imports.epubView
const { EpubCFI } = imports.epubcfi
const { AnnotationRow } = imports.contents
```

`
find foliate on https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate

Somebody explain me this

Comment: What you've shown isn't module importing, it's just assigning consts from the properties of an object referenced via the `imports` identifier, whatever that is. Something above the code you've shown must define `imports` (or it's a global defined in another file). That syntax isn't correct for either CommonJS (which would use `require`) or ESM (which would use an `import` declaration, not a `const` with an initializer).